# Integrated authentication for mysql

Tags: mysql, database, linux, security

When working with MSSQL on Windows I was used to a very convenient feature called integrated authentication. In short, being authenticated in Windows can give you access to the database, so no need to give any specific password. Now I am developing an application on Linux with no user interaction; this application needs to access a mysql database for its own purposes, so how do I let it login? I have found that even though by default a root account is created in mysql, this root account has no connection with unix root, I can use it even if I am not a superuser in Linux, and the password is blank. Of course I can create a dedicated user account in mysql for the needs of my application, but in this case I need to hard-code the password somewhere, which is not nice. Once again - there is no user interaction in my application, so no chance for someone to enter the password. I have a distinct feeling that I am missing something important here. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

First, you really should set a password on the mysql root account...

Second, yeah, you're pretty much going to have to put the password somewhere, unless you set up the application account to use a blank password too...

Answer (score 0):

You can put the settings in a .my.cnf file:

```
[Client]
user=ken
password=ken
host=localhost
database=foo
```

You can use different config files using the --defaults-file option

Some more info on option files at [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html)

Comment: Sorry, but you are not quite getting the point. I am not asking where to store the password - I can pretty much do it in the config file for my own application-but instead I would like to avoid this altogether. Windows integrated authentication means that OS credentials are mapped to DB credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard-code the password, which, as you say, is not particularly nice. E.g. in PHP:

```
 $connection = mysql_connect('HOSTNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
   or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db('DATABASE') or die('Could not select database');
```

Alternatively, you could load the password in from a config file, in which case you could store it in encrypted form, but if someone can see your source-code and see how you decrypt it, they'll be able to decrypt it too.

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward ten years and you can now use an authentication socket to login:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
```

From the console you can than login directly without password by:

```
mysql -u user
```

Not quite sure how you would do the connection string from other applications in that case, I am still looking for that myself...

This method only works for local connections and not for TCP/IP connections. See MySQL Manual [Chapter 11: Enabling Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-configure-authentication.html).